# Button Style in gridview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, gridview, styles

i have a gridview column like this

```
                   <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Share"  Click="fileShareClick" CommandParameter="{Binding Files}"  >
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSharedAllowed}" Value="false">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Im currently using a theme (elysium). As u can see, im using a which makes use of  which targets "Button". However this overwrites my current button theme. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: then set it again in the style..

Comment: @tanuj_loop Sorry, I don't understand too clearly. Could you please explain in more detail, perhaps with an example? Thank you very much

Comment: If you have access to the button style defined by your "elysium" theme you can use the `BasedOn` property on your new button style to inherit the elysium button style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

If you have access to the button style defined by your "elysium" theme you can use the `BasedOn` property on your new button style to inherit the elysium button style